# GNU Radio: Add some custom code in GRC generated code

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I need to apply a math formula (e.g. take a square root) to every sample (of 64 element vector) in the data stream coming out from a GRC signal source block (e.g.Complex to Mag Phase block in the attached GRC flowgraph) using Python code, just before that stream gets passed on to some other block down the stream (e.g. QT GUI Time Sink in the attached GRC flowgraph)

I will be applying phase unwrapping to the 64 sample phase vector before it is displayed to time sink.

[image: Example GRC flowgraph]

Comment: This question is, in its GNU Radio context, pretty clear. I'd have an answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you please guide me through the process of doing that? I've read about PMT and message passing, would that be helpful in this case? I'm new to GNU Radio ecosystem.